# Focus the selected field after OnChange postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a curly problem here.

I'm using a updatePanel to update some things on my page when one of the input's values changes, like this:

```
var Fields = $("input");
        Fields.each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("type") == "text") {
                $(this).change(function () {

                        if (CheckGrupoFields()) {
                            __doPostBack('UpdtOitavas', '');
                        }
                });
            }
        });
```

It's working like a charm but when the user clicks another field or tab it and the postback occurs, the page loses the focus.

I found this script on the internet:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


        var focusedElementId = "";
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

        prm.add_beginRequest(function (source, args) {
            var fe = document.activeElement;
            if (fe != null) {
                focusedElementId = fe.id;
            } else {
                focusedElementId = "";
            }
        });

        prm.add_endRequest(function (source, args) {
            if (focusedElementId != "") {
                $("#" + focusedElementId).focus();
            }
        });}
```

And it's helping me but the focus is going in the control that triggered the OnChange, not in the field that the user clicked.

Is there any way to do it? I want to keep the focus in the input that the user clicked, not in the one that fired the OnChange.

I Hope it's clear.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Suggestions: You can get the Tab Index of the Control that triggered the OnChange event and increment it by 1 and find the Next click/selected control and by its ID set focus() in the endRequest function. Hope you get and it works for you!!!!

Comment: In this way I woundn't get focus in the field that the user clicked but in the next field.